# RxJS to return a new object with an array payload

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to get my NgRX effect to return an action object.  The action object indicates a "success", and needs to return all retrieved institutions as part of the payload.  How do I do this?  Please note that the block inside of the `mergeMap` does not work.  I need to return all the retrieved institutions as part of a payload after retrieving them.

```
  @Effect()
  getInstitutions$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(institutionActions.InstitutionActionTypes.GetInstitutions)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        const institutions = this.getInstitutions();
        console.log(institutions);
        return this.getInstitutions();
      }),
      mergeMap((institutions: Institution[]) => {
        // return institutions;
        return {
          type: institutionActions.InstitutionActionTypes.GetInstitutionsSuccess,
          payload: institutions
        };
      })
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to operate on `this.getInstitutions()` as in:

```
@Effect()
getInstitutions$ = this.actions$
  .ofType(institutionActions.InstitutionActionTypes.GetInstitutions)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.getInstitutions().pipe(
        map(institutions => ({
          type: institutionActions.InstitutionActionTypes.GetInstitutionsSuccess,
          payload: institutions
        })),
        catchError(_ => ...) //don't forget to handle errors
      )
    })
  );
```

As a side note, I would encourage you to use action creators, instead of creating action objects "all over the place" - [Let’s have a chat about Actions and Action Creators within NgRx](https://blog.angularindepth.com/lets-have-a-chat-about-actions-and-action-creators-within-ngrx-41277ecc739d)

Answer (score 0):

How about using "map" instaed mergeMap. Can you try following?

```
 @Effect()
  getInstitutions$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(institutionActions.InstitutionActionTypes.GetInstitutions)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        const institutions = this.getInstitutions();
        console.log(institutions);
        return this.getInstitutions();
      }),
      map((institutions: Institution[]) => {
        // return institutions;
        return {
          type: institutionActions.InstitutionActionTypes.GetInstitutionsSuccess,
          payload: institutions
        };
      })
    );
```

Hope that helps!